# Obtener coincidencias con argumento dinámico, regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo una función que recibe por argumento una serie de claves por cada tecla presionada, e.j: tecla z = T,  tecla c = 3, tecla b = 5, lo cual va agregando los valores en una variable vacía (formulaChords) creando un string que pueda ubicar el índice dentro de un objeto y me arroje el valor de dicho índice. Por ejemplo: formulaChords = Tb35, obtengo el valor 'm'

```
var formulaChord = '';
var dictionaryChord = {
    'T5':'5',
    'T35':'',
    'Tb35':'m',
    'T357':'7'
};
```

Estoy usando un patrón simple que hace exactamente lo que necesito `"\\b"+formulaChord+"\\b"` pero mi problema es que no me arroja el valor si el orden cambia, e.j: `formulaChords = T5b3`. En cambio si agrego al índice el siguiente valor separado por coma `'Tb35,T5b3':'m'`, el patrón reconoce la coincidencia.

Lo que pretendo es no agregar más claves al índice, si no obtener las coincidencias con la clave que está, ya que son los mismos valores. He intentado con las siguientes expresiones `/\b(abc)\b/g` o `"\b["+formulaChord+"]+\b"` pero no obtengo ningún resultado.

Esta es la función:

```
function chords(notes, intervals) {
formulaChord += intervals;

Object.keys(dictionaryChord).filter(function(formula,index) {
    // "\\b"+formulaChord+"\\b" /\b(abc)\b/g  "\b["+formulaChord+"]+\b"
    if(formula.match("\\b"+formulaChord+"\\b")) {
        console.log('chord: '+ Object.values(dictionaryChord)[index]);
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
});

console.log(intervals);
}
```

Gracias por cualquier orientación o respuesta.

Comment: Cómo invocas `chords()` ? No me queda claro que es `intervals` ni `notes`

Comment: chords() se invoca mediante la función de keyup de javascript, como lo había escrito el argumento intervals recibe los valores que asigne a cada tecla e.j: tecla z = T, tecla c = 3, tecla b = 5, estos valores se envían a chords(keysPress) cada vez que se presiona la tecla correspondiente, el argumento notes por el momento no tiene ninguna importancia, está de sobra.

Comment: Se debería encontrar **cualquier** combinación del índice del objeto? Por ejemplo, has dicho que la solución debería encontrar `Tb35` dada la entrada `T5b3`. Pero ¿también se debería encontrar para los casos `T35b`, `bT53`, `b35T`, ... etc?

Comment: Así es, el orden siempre va estar variando dependiendo del patrón de las teclas pressionadas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes hacer eso simplemente con expresiones regulares. Pero para solucionarlo simplemente bastaría con que al comparar las claves de `dictionaryChord` y el string `formulaChord`, ambos estuviesen ordenados.

Para el caso de `dictionaryChord`, lo ideal sería que al definir ese objecto ya te encargues tú de definir el valor de las claves de manera ordenada (números, mayúsculas y minúsculas)

Por ejemplo, en lugar de definir tu hash así:

```
var dictionaryChord = {
  'T5':'5',
  'T35':'',
  'Tb35':'m',
  'T357':'7'
};
```

Defínelo así:

```
var dictionaryChord = {
  '5T':'5',
  '35T':'',
  '35Tb':'m',
  '357T':'7'
};
```

Si por alguna razón no quisieras cambiarlo o no se pudiera, simplemente defínelo como quieras y luego en tiempo de ejecución crea uno nuevo ordenado.

Una vez tenemos el hash ordenado (y también formulachords) ya podemos comparar con un simple `indexOf`.

Un ejemplo podría ser así:

```js
var formulaChord = '';
var dictionaryChord = {
  'T5':'5',
  'T35':'',
  'Tb35':'m',
  'T357':'7'
};
var dictionaryChordSorted = {};

// Función para ordenar un string
function sortStr(str) {
  return str.split('').sort().join('');
}

// Preparar nuestro nuevo objeto (con claves ordenadas)
Object.keys(dictionaryChord).forEach(element => {
  dictionaryChordSorted[sortStr(element)] = dictionaryChord[element];
});

function chords(notes, intervals) {
  // Acumulamos formulaChord y ordenamos el resultado
  formulaChord = sortStr(formulaChord + intervals);
  console.log('FormulaChord acumulada: ' + formulaChord);
  
  return Object.keys(dictionaryChordSorted).filter(function(formula, index) {
    // Como formulaChord está ordenada y formula también, 
    // podemos simplemente comparar
    return formula.indexOf(formulaChord) > -1;
  });
}

console.log(chords(null, '5'));
console.log(chords(null, 'T'));
console.log(chords(null, '3'));
console.log(chords(null, 'b'));
console.log(chords(null, 'z'));
```

Comment: Gracias por tu repuesta Julio ,me ha dado la idea de una solución sin Regex, aunque sería bueno saber si algún experimentado en expresiones regulares puede compartir alguna idea, ya que me queda la duda de si realmente no se puede lograr solo con expresiones regulares.

Comment: Como poder se puede hacer, pero no tiene mucho sentido. Lo que no puedes tener es una expresión regular 'genérica' que te sirva para todo, pero en cada iteración puedes montar una expresión regular nueva en basada en el contenido acumulado de `FormulaChord`. Por ejemplo, si `FormulaChord` vale `Tb35`, prepararías la regex: `(?=.*?T)(?=.*?b)(?=.*?3)(?=.*?5).*` Demo aquí: https://regex101.com/r/Pznnme/1/ En cualquier caso la solución sin regex debería ser más rápida (e intuitiva). Un `indexOf` siempre va a ser más rápido que una expresión regular